# TabController Example Object creating errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, tabcontrol

I have a 5 tab expanded version of the TabController example supplied with Xcode 4.
I need to do some maths so have created an object to manage this.
The object is inserted just to the tab view that requires it.
It compiles fine.

HOWEVER when I click on a button to update the answer on screen it errors.

```
label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", c];
```

without the above line it doesn't.

The first line the debugger cites, in main.m, is:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SolarAppDelegate class]));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what type is your 'c' variable and how do you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the type of value you are having in c.

Also in new xcode you need to change some settings and add Exception break point if you want to know the exact error point. 
If you have not added any exception break point then it will show you to this line only

Comment: Hi, I was playing about with the code and changed the name of a delegate and presume the connection would adjust. Instead I had to delete it and recreate it with the new name and the error has gone. Many thanks.